# How to CROP Images in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image, camera, crop

Hello i am using UIImagePicker to take images but while picking images i want to CROP that image.. How to do that

i am able to pick images from gallery to imageview but while selecting image i need to crop the image.

I have tried below code:

```
 class AddNewEventViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imgPick: UIImageView!

var picker = UIImagePickerController()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true
}
  @IBAction func addProfileBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    actionSheetController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.contentView
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action -> Void in
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
    let takePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "TakePhoto", style: .default) { action -> Void in
        self.openCameraPicker()
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(takePictureAction)
    let choosePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ChooseFromLibrary", style: .default) { action -> Void in
        self.openPhotoGallery()
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(choosePictureAction)
    //Present the
    self.present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func openCameraPicker() {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
    picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(picker,animated: true,completion: nil)
}
func openPhotoGallery() {
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    picker.allowsEditing = true

    picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
// MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let img = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage{
        imgPick.image = img
    }
    else if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imgPick.image = image
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

like this i am getting.. no crop

[image]

here i am getting images from gallery to imageview but not getting crop.

How to crop the images, please help me with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check with your code and i found you are missing to set `delegate`  of `UIImagePickerController`

I try with `photoLibrary` for now

```
class ImagePickerViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView:UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.openPhotoGallery()
    }

    func openPhotoGallery() {

        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let img = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage{
            imageView.image = img
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: i havent add that code.. but i `picker.delegate = self` still not able to crop... now i edited the post as well

Comment: Added to your VC -> `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`, `UINavigationControllerDelegate` ?

Comment: pls check once my edited question.. just edited aginn.. am i missing anything

Comment: r u able to crop images.. pls need code.. any working code.. or working sample will be helpful

Comment: pls post ur whole code or if u have sample project in github pls share.. i am using Xcode 11.3 version.. i need the code pls share

Comment: sorry for disturbing again.. i have copy paste ur code in my sample project.. i am not getting crop.. pls look at my OUTPUT above

Comment: i have sample project in gitgub https://github.com/SwiftSamples/Test.Prj. .. did i miss anything to add

Comment: i have added `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription `. as well in prj still not able to crop

Comment: I checked your `Github` demo and it's working fine.

Comment: can u share knowledge about this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61813194/how-to-sync-phone-contacts-in-background-to-app-in-ios-swift